# Effective Eiffel Postcondition for Ensuring that Array is sorted

Tags: arrays, sorting, eiffel, post-conditions

I have implemented a query that tells if array is sorted or not. I want to make a good postcondition that will effectively check if array is sorted using `across` or something else.

I tried to do this like this:

```
is_sorted (a: ARRAY [INTEGER]): BOOLEAN
        -- Given an array, tell if it's sorted in ascending order
    require
        array_set: a /= Void
    local
        i, j, temp: INTEGER
    do
        Result := True

        from
            i := a.lower
            j := i + 1
        invariant
            (i >= a.lower) and (i <= a.upper)
        until
            i = (a.upper) or (Result = False)
        loop
            if a[i] > a[j] then
                Result := False
            end

            i := i + 1
            j := j + 1
        variant
            a.count - i + 1
        end -- End of loop

    ensure
          -- Check if ARRAY is sorted here
    end
```

I tried to write something like this:

```
ensure
    across a as el all (el.item <= el.forth.item) end
```

But this obviously doesn't work because `el.forth` is not a query, yet a command.

How can I make this `across` work or should I do something else?

Comment: Can you use something like `across 1 |..| (a.count - 1) as la_index all a.at(la_index.item) <= a.at(la_index.item + 1) end` ?

Comment: @LouisM yes, of course. That's what I was looking for. Put it in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over indexes instead of over the array. Something like that:

`across 1 |..| (a.count - 1) as la_index all a.at(la_index.item) <= a.at(la_index.item + 1) end`

Answer (score 2):

To complement Louis's answer, here are some more variants. First, the same version, that takes into account that array indexes do not necessary start with `1`:

```
across a.lower |..| (a.upper - 1) as i all a [i.item] <= a [i.item + 1] end
```

Unfortunately, this version does not work when `upper` is the minimum integer value. In this case `a.upper - 1` overflows and the iteration gets a wrong integer interval. The solution is to stick to the original range of indexes, but with a condition that the last element is not compared:

```
across a.lower |..| a.upper as i until i.item >= a.upper all a [i.item] <= a [i.item + 1] end
```

Instead of iterating over an interval, the original array can be iterated directly if the last element is excluded from the comparison:

```
across a as i until i.target_index >= a.upper all i.item <= a [i.target_index + 1] end
```

or, using a dedicated query `is_last`:

```
across a as i until i.is_last all i.item <= a [i.target_index + 1] end
```